# Connection between two computers with Ubuntu 10.04 for transfer files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, lan

I have two computers: one is connected with router by wi-fi and another is connected with router by lan. How I can optimal organize connection between two computers with Ubuntu 10.04 for transfer files? What Do I do? Can I share some folders,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share them with ssh: Local - Connect to server - SSH and fill in machine name, user and directory.
After that you'll have the other machine directory (and whole subtree) mounted on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be setup Samba on the computers and share directories between the two.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple, but non-FLOSS, $0 solution, you could try running Dropbox on both and sharing that way. You can change the folder which is sunk after installation.

This will upload your data to the Dropbox servers, however.

Comment: Since OP has a LAN, it is a LOT faster to use it instead of using internet connection 2 times to copy/share files.